# React-Native fast refresh issue

Tags: react-native

My Fast Refresh despite being active stopped working across all of my react native projects also I created a new project and it is not working there too. My react-native version 0.69.1

I have tried and it never works

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm ./.git/index.lock
yarn start and npx react-native start
simulator clear cache
```

Do you have any other solution ideas

Comment: did you stop metro in the terminal?

Comment: have you set Debug server host & port in settings?

Comment: `npx react-native start --reset-cache`?

Comment: npx react-native start --reset-cache , it didn't work.

@SanjayKochrekar Debug server host & port in settings , I didn't make any additional settings. How will I do

Answer (score 0):

just add `cache-clean` to `start` key in `scripts`  **"package.json"**

> ```
> "start": "react-native start --reset-cache cache clean"
> ```

then use

yarn || npm start